# find 'x' examples of match string in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to find best way to find x examples of string in long list:

```
List = [123xyz, 456xyz, 678xyz, 123abc, 123ok, 123yes, 456abc, 456ok, noyes, yesno, yes123]
```

and i want to find all pair with '123'* or all pair of *'abc' but minimum pair 'x'

```
example '123'* x=3 : 123xyz, 123abc, 123ok
example *'abc' x =2 : 123abc, 456abc
```

someone have idea or examples of code to find this on list?

Comment: Loop over the list and check if the string starts with `123` or ends with `abc`?  Also, which group would `123abc` fall into?

Comment: What do you mean 'x'?

Comment: What do you mean by "pair"?

Comment: Add the the output you want to your question

Comment: Also show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your examples suggest that you're looking for a maximum of x number of matches (not a minimum).

If you're only looking to match on prefixes and suffixes, you could use the startswith() and endswith() functions.

In order to limit the result to a specific number of matches, you can simply use a range index

for example:

```
# match "123*" x=3
result = [ s for s in List if s.startswith("123") ][:3]  

# match "*abc" x=2
result = [ s for s in List if s.endswith("abc") ][:2]
```